# Using Importxml accross multiple cells in Google sheets

Tags: xml, automation, google-sheets-formula, metadata

I am trying to use importxml to extract titles from a list of urls in google sheets.
My URL list is in cell c2-c154
an example value =IMPORTXML("https://yahoo.com","//title")

How can i rewrite the formula in importxml such that allows me to fetch the url title from cells c2-154 (so i can copy paste the formula for multiple rows)

Researched online, read multiple forums and did trial and error

Answer (score 0):

try placing this in the cell in the first row:

```
={"Title"; MAP(C2:C154, LAMBDA(_url, IMPORTXML(_url, "//title")))}
```